# Examples of how to use NServiceBus with NServiceBus.Ninject-CI in ASP.NET MVC 3 solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, nservicebus

I would like to experiment with NServiceBus using ASP.NET MVC 3. I've got a solution with NServiceBus installed, plus NinjectMVC3 and NServiceBus.Ninject-CI. Trouble is, I have no idea how to setup NServiceBus stuff in the NinjectMVC3.cs file in App_Start.

Rather annoyingly I'm having trouble finding any examples of how to use NServiceBus.Ninject-CI (I hate it when people don't bother giving examples of how to use their stuff).

Can someone help me get started please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Load a module like this into the kernel to provide access to the bus

```cs
public class NServiceBusModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Bind<IBus>().ToConstant(this.CreateBus()).InSingletonScope();
    }

    private IBus CreateBus()
    {
        return NServiceBus.Configure.WithWeb()
            .NinjectBuilder(this.Kernel)

            ... // put NServiceBus config here 

            .CreateBus()
            .Start();
    }
}
```

Read the NServiceBus documentation about how to configure NServiveBus: 
http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/containers/ninject
http://docs.particular.net/samples/web/asp-mvc-application/

Comment: Many thanks for that, I managed to get the code to compile now. Having problems getting my site to use version 3.0.0 of NServiceBus since it keeps finding a version 1.0.0 in the bin folder?!! I don't know where it's getting that from. Weird.

Comment: This seems to have been broken in a recent version... now it just spits out the error `No endpoint name could be generated, please specify your own convention using Configure.DefineEndpointName(...)`... even though I already **did** specify that. It almost works binding `ToMethod`/`InSingletonScope`, but on the second attempt it always reports multiple bindings for `IBus`. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, I figured out a workaround; you have to configure the bus in the NinjectModule *without* creating/starting it - which creates some sort of mystery binding - and then rebind `IBus` on the next line to a method that creates and starts it (second step is necessary in order to do any post-start actions like `Install`). Hope that helps anyone else who's struggling with the betas.

Comment: Hi Remo - could you clarify this? Passing the kernel to NinjectBuilder appears to actually create an IBus binding - so this code sample causes two bindings to be created for IBus.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help someone. I had a lot of trouble finding sample code for getting ninject working within NServiceBus.

This code below works for me in place of the more common Castle version:

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Publisher, IWantCustomInitialization
{
    #region IWantCustomInitialization Members

    public void Init()
    {
        Configure
            .With()
            .NinjectBuilder(CreateKernel())
            .XmlSerializer()
            .MsmqTransport();

        SetLoggingLibrary.Log4Net(XmlConfigurator.Configure);
    }

    protected IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        kernel.Load<MyCustomNinjectModule>();

        return kernel;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

with the ninject module being the usual format, ie:

```
public class MyCustomNinjectModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind(typeof(ILogger<>)).To(typeof(Log4NetLogger<>));  
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Max for the code sample, very much appreciated. I've not looked at this stuff for a long time, so I will need to have look at this again.